# Installing two different Nvidia drivers at the same time

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia

I have a GTX1070ti for which the latest driver is `527.37`.

I bought a NVS 310 for which the latest driver is `392.68`.

I would like to use both cards simultaneously for different monitors. However, when I install one driver the other gets removed and viceversa.

Is there any way I can use both of these cards with their drivers at the same time?

Currently, the best I could do was run the 1070ti drivers and the NVS310 without drivers. The monitors on the 1070ti work fine but the NVS310 only outputs to one out of two monitors connected to it, filling up only the center area of the monitor.

Comment: I think - not sure - the 390 branch, being in long term support, should support the GTX1070ti as well. It may not be the best but it may work for your setup.